# How can I capture the data frames from a list in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, global

I want to combine data frames with different columns in Python Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd 

first_df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'a':np.random.randn(6),
    'b':np.random.choice( [5,7,np.nan], 6),
    'c':np.random.choice( ['panda','python','shark'], 6)})

second_df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'a':np.random.randn(6),
    'b':np.random.choice( [5,7,np.nan], 6)})

third_df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'a':np.random.randn(6)})
```

I got a list of dataframes

```
df_list = %who_ls DataFrame 
print(len(df_list))
df_list
```

but I do not know how to capture the dataframes objects themselves so that I can combine them:

```
pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Do you think indexing like `df_list[0]` ?

Comment: @jezrael indexing returns a string because df_list is a list of strings. I want the dataframe object itself.

Comment: `the_df_list = [globals()[df_name] for df_name in df_list]`.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure why you use who_ls, if you want to combine dataframes just make a list of them like this:

```
df = pd.concat([first_df, second_df, third_df])
```

edit: i strongly suggest you avoid using who_ls and globals() to do what you want, there are a couple of things that could go wrong if you change your code in the futrue, plus it's not much readable. but it will work as someone already suggested in the comments.
but please consider making a list of objects as you load/create them to avoid this.

Comment: It works but I do not want to type the dataframe names because I am working with a large number of data frames.

Comment: @Hamideh you could extract object from it's name using globals()  but i think there is a cleaner way to do it, where do the large number of data frames come from? maybe you should catch them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of all dfs stored in your memory using:

```
df_list = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
print(df_list)
>> ['first_df', 'second_df', 'third_df']
```